# DM'ing a specific user ID

Tags: javascript, node.js, discord, discord.js

```js
const Discord = require('discord.js');
const bot = new Discord.Client();
const PREFIX = "!!";

bot.on("message", async message => {
  if(message.content.toLowerCase().startsWith(`${PREFIX}suggest`)) {
     //a user says "!!suggest more commands"
     message. /*ID <@206377170707152906>*/ .send(`The user {$message.author.name.toString()} has given a suggestion; "${message.content.toString()}`);
     //then a DM is sent to the <@206377170707152906> ID saying (the ID is different from user ABC123's ID) "The user ABC123 has given a suggestion; "!!suggest more commands"
     message.author.send(`The suggestion "${message.content.toString()}" has been sent!`);
     return;
   }}
```

How do I put the ID "<@206377170707152906>" into the message.send so that the DM is sent to the "<@206377170707152906>" ID?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To send a Direct Message you need the User Object. You can get the cached users from `client.users`, but the user might not be in cache. To "load" that user and send him a message you can do something like this:

```
client.users.fetch('123456789').then((user) => {
    user.send("My Message");
});
```

Dont forget to replace `123456789` with the ID that you want. In this case you want only the numbers, you don't need the `<@...>`

Comment: I have '401: Unauthorized', /api/v7/users/:userId